# Programmatically add and connect Data Flow components in SSIS in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Is there a high quality sample code for Data Flow Components in SSIS?

I specifically need the following:

1. OLE DB Source
2. Derive Column Transformation
3. Flat File Destination.

Lets say that the table schema comprises of two columns, ID of varchar(2) and Description of varchar(20).  The output is a flat file ID of 1 char (just get the first character of ID), and Description of 10 chars (just get the first 10 characters of Description).  It would be great if it were in C#.

Lets assume that I know pretty well to add and connect Control Flow Tasks and Connection Managers.

Thanks in advance for your expertise.

EDIT:

We only have SQL Server 2005, so examples in this version would be a great help.  But it would really be nice to have 2008 to use ezAPI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are samples that do this using "raw" SSIS API, but it is probably easier to use EzAPI for this.

Matt's post on SSIS blog contains a sample that creates a very similar package, it should be trivial to replace Sort with Derived Column:
http://blogs.msdn.com/mattm/archive/2008/12/30/ezapi-alternative-package-creation-api.aspx